# Applying overflow hidden before wrapping the next element

Tags: html, css

I have a layout with a set of divs each containing three fields in different fonts displayed as:

```
Author
Title Date
```

thus structured something like:

```
<div>
  <div class="author">author</div>
  <div>
    <span class="title">title</span>
    <span class="date">date</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The blocks are fixed width but the fields are variable width. I want the author and title to be cut off when they are too long so I applied:

```
.author, .title {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This works for the author, but the title gets cut off only when the date is already moved to the next line. I'd like the title to be cut of as soon as the date hits the right side like this:

```
+---------------------------------+
| This is a very very long auto...|
| This is a long ti... (yesterday)|
+---------------------------------+
```

Is this possible with css?

**EDIT**

Some clarification. I understand how I can give the title a maximum width as shown in various answers, but that is not what I need. The entire box has a fixed width, and ALL fields have variable width.

BUT the second line needs to be cut off at the first field (title) instead of the last field (date). **Thus I'd like the max-width of the title to depend on the width of the date.** Examples:

```
+---------------------------------+
| This is a very very long auto...|
| Short title (2 days ago)        |
+---------------------------------+

+---------------------------------+
| Some author                     |
| Bit Longer tit.. (long time ago)|
+---------------------------------+

+---------------------------------+
| Another author                  |
| This is a long ti... (yesterday)|
+---------------------------------+
```

I don't see how this is possible with CSS even when I restrict it to cutting edge browsers or when I start hacking the HTML with ugly things like tables.

Yet, it seems like a cleanest way to display the data to the end user, so I'm hoping for someone who knows the magic trick...

Comment: really belongs on doctype, unless you want a Javascript answer, which is certainly doable.

Comment: What do you mean belongs on doctype?

Comment: BTW I don't mind if the solution needs javascript...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have it working in FF using some Javascript (javascript). I haven't got it working with the ellipses yet - but with a little more work its doable (using the background image approach).

Copy paste this into a .html file to see a proof of concept - when loaded resize your browser winder so its narrower to see it automatically shift stuff around and give you the wrapping effect you want.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <style type='text/css'>
   .author, .title {
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
   }
   .title, .date {
    float: left;
   }
   .date {
    margin-left:10px;
   }

   .author {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
   }
   .title {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
   }
   .date {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
   }
  </style>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   $.resizeHeader = function() {
    var _title = $('#title');
    var _date = $('#date');
    var _container = $('#headingContainer');
    _title.css('width','auto');
    var _containerWidth = _container.width();
    var _titleWidth = _title.outerWidth(true);
    var _dateWidth = _date.outerWidth(true);
    if ((_dateWidth+_titleWidth)>_containerWidth) {
     var _deltaWidth = (_dateWidth+_titleWidth)-_containerWidth;
     var _newTitleWidth = _titleWidth-_deltaWidth;
     _title.width(_newTitleWidth);
    }
   }

   $(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
     $.resizeHeader();
    }).resize();;
   })  
  </script>
 </head>

 <div id='headingContainer'>
  <div class="author">This is an author title</div>
  <div>
   <span class="title" id='title'>This is the title which is very long and prone to spill over and over and over and over and over</span>
   <span class="date" id='date'>The Date</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice work! I guess css-only is not an option so Javascript it has to be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

'span' elements are treated as inline unless otherwise specified.  You need to constrain the width of `.title` before it hits the side of the container div.

Something like the following might work:

```
.title{display:block;max-width:60px;}
```

**EDIT**

Okay, so a little more playing and this seems to accomplish what you are after with your markup (assuming it's named "#wrapper")

```
div#wrapper{width:160px;border:1px solid #ccc;overflow:auto}
.author, .title {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.title{display:block;width:60%;float:left}
.date{display:block;width:40%;float:right;}
```

Comment: That would work if the date-field has a fixed width. I don't know the exact max-width of title. That's the problem.

Comment: Try setting both the title and date to `display:block` and setting the width as a percentage.  If the container is fixed width, then this might just work. You may have to play around with the percentages to get it to look right.

Comment: I see what you suggest, but my problem is that I don't know the width of the date-field. Percentages won't help. Some dates are "less then a minute ago", some are "1-1-2009".

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like floating the date right. Also, keep in mind that Firefox doesn't support `text-overflow: ellipsis`; you'd have to use something like Matt Snider's method at http://mattsnider.com/css/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/ ...

If you can't float the date, what you want is impossible. You'll need to rethink your design.

Comment: If I float the date to the right, and the title gets to big, it will be pushed below the date, regardless of overflow & whitespace. I guess what I want is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution if I correctly understand what you're trying to do.  Even though you don't know the width of the title, there is potential for the title to overflow.  Since that's the case, then you should be the one to determine the when and where of how it overflows.  I don't see a way around not setting max-width.

```
.author, .title {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.title {
  max-width: 150px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.date {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

<div>
  <div class="author">author</div>
  <div>
    <span class="title">Really really really really long title</span>
    <span class="date">Date</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Browser Compatibility of max-width](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/max-width)

Comment: Your solution will result in the title having a fixed max-width instead of the entire box.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe fix the height of the author element as well?

```
.author {
    height: 1.2em;
}
```

Might not work, CSS pretty much follows the basic flow layout of HTML, which assumes that the height of elements will vary with their content.

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve it. I still need to specify a "dynamic" max-width

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood the question. Yeah, CSS doesn’t really let you specify dimensions based on the content of other elements.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to absolutely position the <span class="date"> element to the bottom right of the container <div> and set a background image on it as well (containing an ellipsis) and make sure the z-index is set above the <span class="title"> element. Then you just let the .title element run underneath the .date element and all should be well.

```
div
{
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.author, .title
{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
}
.date
{
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url(/images/ellipsis.gif);
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-left: 10px; /* Assuming that the bg image is this size */
}
.title
{
    z-index: 0;
}
```

It's working for me in FF3.5, Chrome and IE8, though as has been mentioned the *text-overflow: ellipsis* doesn't work well cross browser.

Comment: Your solution works for long titles & dates (example 2 & 3) but if the title & date are short (example 1), it still shows the ellipsis and the date is still right aligned.